# Create new isolated scope programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, leaflet, angularjs-compile

I am trying to create popup html to go into a leafletjs marker popup.

I have the following partial:

```
 <div class="popup">
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a class="popup-info" ng-click="onInfoClicked()">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
           </a>
        </div>

        <div class="popup-title">
          {{title}}
        </div>

        <div class="popup-subtitle">
          {{subtitle}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following directive:

```
app.directive('leafletPopup', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl:  "app/partials/leaflet-popup.html",
    scope: {
      feature: '=',
      popupInfo: '&'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.title = $scope.feature.properties.title;
      $scope.subtitle = $scope.feature.properties.description;

      $scope.onInfoClicked = function() {
         $scope.popupInfo({feature: feature});
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I have a controller that provides a function to generate the html for each marker that I am going to place on the map:

```
function html(feature) {
  var el = angular.element('<div leaflet-popup="feature" popup-info="onPopupInfo(feature)"></div>');
  var compiled = $compile(el);
  var newScope = $scope.$new(true); // create new isolate scope
  newScope.feature = feature;  // inject feature into the scope
  newScope.onPopupInfo = function(feature) {  // inject function into scope
    // do something with the click
    showFeatureDetails(feature);
  }
  compiled(newScope);

  return el[0];
}
```

Works perfectly.  Great right?

I have read in a couple of places that its not recommended to create your own scope manually as you have to make sure you also destroy it manually.

Lets say I have a bunch of markers on my map, and each has a popup.  Do I need to track all the new scopes I create in my controller and call destroy on them?  When?  Only if my marker gets removed from the map?

I could just skip angular and build the entire html element with jquery and attach the onclick to a function, but that is also not pretty.  And why skip angular?

Seems overly complicated, which probably means I am doing this the hard way ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not creating a directive for this?  Seems like a perfect use for it.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat what do you mean by create a directive?  I did create a directive 'leafletPopup'.  You mean a different directive?  I need to give leaflet html to bind to the popup.  I am manually building a simple div that includes my directive.  Is there a different/better way?

Comment: Wondering... Are you using the angular-leaflet-directive?

Comment: @iH8 nope.  Unfortunately that directive is too limiting for my use case.  I add/remove a lot of markers dynamically.  That directive rebuilds the entire GeoJSON collection on a single change.  It also only allows for one geojson layer.  I have multiple geojson layers.

Comment: I don't know enough about the popups I guess, but from where you call `html()`, could you just have a directive that creates those divs?